# Best practices on splitting 12 V 20 amp supply into 5 devices?

Tags: wiring, 12v

I am running a 48 V to 12 V converter rated for up to 60 A on my custom pedicab setup. I'm fairly new at all things electrical and want to get this right.

I have five different devices that hopefully will not pull more than 20 A at a time from that 12 V supply. I will be running an audio amp (rated up to 15 A but I doubt it'll ever get that high), a 16 ft LED light strip (6 A), a set of fairy lights (1 A?), the front headlight and back lights that come installed on the bike (3 A?), and I also thought about adding a 12 V to 5 V USB supply to power my phone. I need to split that 12 V supply into all these devices.

Is this just a matter of using the proper gauge wire off the 12 V supply and then crimping 5 wires onto it? All the splitters I see on Amazon are barrel connectors for CC-TV rated for a total of 5 A. If I am going to actually buy a splitter, I need to buy it in person tomorrow? What sort of store sells such a thing and what is it I would need?

Thank you in advance, for any and all help!

Comment: Assuming all other components are correct and suitable(do the LEDs have resistors?  Probably but if not you'll want current control, you can indeed terminate the devices in parallel to the power supply, and you should make sure that each device has it's own correctly rated fuse.

Comment: @KH Is that an answer? Why not put it in the answer section?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I think he got 48V from a battery pack, pedicab with AC voltage sounds futuristic I think.

Comment: Would this work:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-22-10-AWG-10-Circuit-Terminal-Block-1-Pack-GTB-410/202522613

Isn't the fuse simply there in the event of a short? It has nothing to do with regulating the draw right? If a device, for instant the 16ft LED light strip that has a total wattage of 72, so 6a, is plugged in directly to 12v power, will it simply ask for those 6a and hold steady there once it's got them? Again... am I understanding correctly that a fuse is simply for in the event of a short and whatever happens to cause too much power to flow?

Comment: yes 48v from a battery pack, converter by a 48 to 12v converter rated for 60a.

AC voltage would be a bit wild. :)

Comment: It says \$30\mathrm{A@}600\mathrm{V}\$ [here](https://www.gardnerbender.com/en/p/GTB-410/10-Pole-Terminal-Block), but its not doable, terminal block is not for splitting. See the bus bar with fuse configuration which already answered by K H. Also you could increase the power efficiency of your system by using 12V battery pack instead (including the BMS), thus eliminating needs of a converter.

Answer (score 2):

LEDs are subject to thermal runaway.  You can google "LED thermal runaway" to find out about that, but long story short they need some form of current control.

At any rate, assuming all of your devices are acceptable for the voltage range they will experience, you can connect them all to the voltage supply.  However:

Each conductor supplying power to a device must be rated for the maximum current it is expected to draw, the highest temperature it will experience and the highest voltage it will sustain.  For a 6A LED, a 6.4-7A fuse should be fine, and a wire rated for 6A.  You can go to larger sizes of wire to reduce volt drop and increase efficiency, but if you do so, you should still size the fuse based on the load.  Cheap inline automotive fuse holders are ubiquitous.  Make sure the components you use are rated for use in your area (for Canada you want Canadian Standards Association(CSA) or Underwriter's Labs(UL) approval) if your vehicle counts as a vehicle.

Each time conductor size is reduced, the smaller conductor should be protected by an overcurrent device(fuse should be fine) to protect from shorts without having to shut down the whole system.  Each fuse should be set as low as practicable, meaning it should have the smallest possible current value without ever tripping during normal operation.  Your PSU has 60A overcurrent protection(or if not you should add it), which won't do anything to protect a 5A load or a 10A wire.

For splitting the output of that converter, you can run a wire capable of 60A to a bus bar.  A bus bar is basically a block of conductor with screws for the purpose of tap connections.  Use inline fuseholders on each smaller conductor that taps off the bar.  You may be able to use an automotive fusebox as well, but keep the fuses accessible and as close as possible to the source.

Comment: He has 3 m (16') of LEDstrip so there is built-in current limiting. so runaway is not an issue, but over current on stripleds in series maybe. He must not wire more than 2 reels in series. Parallel is OK.

Comment: KH, thank you for a very nice and thorough explanation.

@SunnyskyguyEE75 Why do you say there is built in current limiting? To be clear, I did not buy a strip with a power adapter, but simply the strip itself.

Comment: Do buck converters already have this protection built in? For instance, does this little one for USB use already have it?: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00OXZ06I4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @JacobCammack  Does the LEDstrip have an SMD resistor every 3 LED's? those are the current limiters for 12V only.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Good point.  I was picturing a more mysterious fixture, but those dimensions do scream LED tape.  I'll leave it in there just because it's still an example of a property of a load that one might want to check.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this just a matter of using the proper gauge wire off the 12 v supply and then crimping 5 wires onto it?

Essentially, yes. You should take a cue from car or motorcycle wiring though, as that's what your pedicab setup is. First, the wire from your 12V source should be appropriately fused. In the US, the fuses are rated for their expected max load, so a 25 Amp fuse would be wise. Then wire it with 10 AWG wire, to a fuse block, with appropriate fuses and wiring to your accessories. If weather is a concern, make it waterproof. Something like this fuse block:

[image]

While you could just use the individual fuses or just the main fuse, its better to have both sections fused. The cost is minimal for peace of mind.

All of which you can buy at any auto or boat part shop, same day. Some home improvement stores also carry fuse blocks but an auto parts store is easier.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Am I correct in assuming if I use a fuse block, that it is itself a splitter as well and therefore I wouldn't need one? (I know this is probably a very obvious question but the situation is a bit high stress so I'm really covering all my bases.)

Comment: @JacobCammack yes. Depending on the fuse block, there is one input shared to each of the fused outputs, or there is an independent input for each fuse. You can daisy chain the cable from input to input.

Comment: Thanks so much for everyone's help. Bought a 6 way fuse block splitter off of Amazon. Works just fine. Here's a link to it. Cheers. :)

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07GYTZF35/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1